# C++ dll define static member

Tags: c++, static-members, dllexport

I'm making my first steps into DLLs and I'm trying to write a class for a linked list and export it to .dll. When I try to define a static member, I get compilation error:

[Error] definition of static data member 'dll::Container::IDcount' of dllimport'd class

Here is my code:

container.h

```
 #ifndef _CONTAINER_H_
 #define _CONTAINER_H_

 #if BUILDING_DLL
 #define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
 #else
 #define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
 #endif

 #define DEFAULT_SIZE 8

namespace dll{
 typedef union{
    char _c;
    short _s;
    int _i;
    long _l;
    float _f;
    double _d;
 }unit_t;

 typedef unsigned long long size_t;

 class DLLIMPORT Container{
    private:
        static size_t IDcount;
        unit_t* data;
        size_t size;
        size_t bytes;
        size_t memberID;
        Container *next;
        Container *prev;

    public:
        Container();
        Container(size_t size);
        Container(const Container &copy);
        ~Container();
 }; 
}

 #endif
```

container.cpp

```
#include "container.h"

namespace dll{

 size_t Container::IDcount = 0;

 Container::Container(){
    this->memberID = 0;
    this->size = DEFAULT_SIZE;
    this->bytes = DEFAULT_SIZE * sizeof(unit_t);
    this->data = new unit_t[DEFAULT_SIZE];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < DEFAULT_SIZE; i++)
        this->data[i] = {0x0};
    this->next = nullptr;
    this->prev = nullptr;
 }

 Container::Container(size_t size)
    : size(size){
    this->memberID = 0;
    this->bytes = this->size * sizeof(unit_t);
    this->data = new unit_t[this->size];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        this->data[i] = {0x0};
    this->next = nullptr;
    this->prev = nullptr;
 }

 Container::Container(const Container &copy){
    this->memberID = copy.memberID;
    this->size = copy.size;
    this->bytes = copy.bytes;
    this->data = new unit_t[this->size];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        this->data[i] = copy.data[i];
    this->next = copy.next;
    this->prev = copy.prev;
 }

 Container::~Container(){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        this->data[i]= {0x0};
    delete[] this->data;
    this->memberID = 0x0;
    this->size = 0x0;
    this->bytes = 0x0;
    if(!(this->prev))
        this->prev->next = this->next;      
    if(!(this->next))
        this->next->prev = this->prev;
    this->next = nullptr;
    this->prev = nullptr;
 }
}
```

Am I missing something?

thanks in advance

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?  Do you have `BUILDING_DLL` defined to a nonzero value when compiling `container.cpp`?

Comment: I get the error on the line 4, `size_t Container::IDcount = 0;` and **BUILDING_DLL** is defined and by the IDE and has a value 1. I'm using DEVC++ 5.11, it uses MinGW with g++11 standards.

Answer (score 0):

The `BUILDING_DLL` macro definition doesn't make it to the compiler (even if shown by *Dev-C++* as defined). Below is a small example that builds your files (**with no changes**) into a *.dll* from *cmdline* (you can ignore the last part, as it is a test to see if it also builds with *VStudio*).

**Output**:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050979671>set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Install\x64\MinGW32\MinGW32\7.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050979671>dir /b
> build.bat
> container.cpp
> container.h
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050979671>g++ -shared -fPIC -DBUILDING_DLL=1 -std=c++11 -o container_g++.dll container.cpp
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050979671>dir /b
> build.bat
> container.cpp
> container.h
> container_g++.dll
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050979671>rem NOTE: "container_g++.dll" WAS CREATED
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050979671>rem Building WITHOUT `-DBUILDING_DLL=1`
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050979671>g++ -shared -fPIC -std=c++11 -o container_g++.dll container.cpp
> container.cpp:5:20: warning: 'dll::Container::IDcount' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
>   size_t Container::IDcount = 0;
>                     ^~~~~~~
> container.cpp:7:2: warning: 'dll::Container::Container()' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
>   Container::Container(){
>   ^~~~~~~~~
> container.cpp:18:2: warning: 'dll::Container::Container(dll::size_t)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
>   Container::Container(size_t size)
>   ^~~~~~~~~
> container.cpp:29:2: warning: 'dll::Container::Container(const dll::Container&)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
>   Container::Container(const Container &copy){
>   ^~~~~~~~~
> container.cpp:40:2: warning: 'dll::Container::~Container()' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
>   Container::~Container(){
>   ^~~~~~~~~
> container.cpp:5:9: error: definition of static data member 'dll::Container::IDcount' of dllimport'd class
>   size_t Container::IDcount = 0;
>          ^~~~~~~~~
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050979671>"c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050979671>cl /DBUILDING_DLL=1 container.cpp /MD /Focontainer_msvc.obj /link /dll /out:container_msvc.dll
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x64
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> container.cpp
> Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:container_msvc.exe
> /dll
> /out:container_msvc.dll
> container_msvc.obj
>    Creating library container_msvc.lib and object container_msvc.exp
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050979671>dir /b
> build.bat
> container.cpp
> container.h
> container_g++.dll
> container_msvc.dll
> container_msvc.exp
> container_msvc.lib
> container_msvc.obj
> ```

As seen, `-DBUILDING_DLL=1`:

- When passing it, the *.dll* is built
- When not passing it, the error that you encountered pops up

As I don't have *Dev-C++*, I don't know how to set it from its options (although I think it's something straightforward like going to "*Tools -> Compiler options*" and selecting "*C++ Compiler*" and then add the macro definition), so I'm going to enable it at code level. 
Things are pretty simple, in ***container.cpp*** define `BUILDING_DLL` **before** including *container.h*, like:

```
#define BUILDING_DLL 1
#include "container.h"
```

Personally, I prefer this approach (instead of setting project options), because it only has to be done once, regardless of how many build systems are used to build the code.

Running the command that failed (above), will now generate the *.dll*.

Comment: Did this answer your question?